# Lowess function and plyr

Tags: r, plyr, curve-fitting

I am working with a data frame I created and want to expand it to include a lowess fit. I have been able to add a lowess curve to the plot of my data along with an lm fit but I cannot figure out how to add the lowess values to my data frame.
Please forgive the ugliness of my code as I do everything by brute force (i.e. suggestions for simplification/efficiency are appreciated.) I apologize as I am not allowed to post images. I have a scatterplot with an lm fit yielding an R^2 of .7897 and a lowess curve which well replicates the qqplot of the lm fit. When I get a reputation of "10" I will post it for edification/ease of visualization:

```
##Read in Data
OPM.df <- read.csv("On Peak Mod TMAX.csv", header = TRUE)
 ## Data frame 2008-2012
OPM5.df <- OPM.df[4606:6140,]
##Verify headings
OPM5.df[1,]
SummerOPM5.df <- OPM5.df[month(OPM5.df$Date) >= 6 & month(OPM5.df$Date) <= 9, ]
##@Fit Linear Regression to Data
fitsummerX <- lm(SummerOPM5.df$MaxLoad~SummerOPM5.df$TMAX)
summary(fitsummerX)
##Plot data 
windows()
plot(SummerOPM5.df$TMAX, SummerOPM5.df$MaxLoad, main="Linear Regression Adjusted R-     squared: 0.7897",)
## Add fit lines
abline(fitsummerX, col="red") # regression line (y~x) 
lines(lowess(SummerOPM5.df$TMAX,SummerOPM5.df$MaxLoad), col="blue") # lowess line (x,y)

## plyr augmentation of df
SummerOPM5.df <- ddply(SummerOPM5.df, .(Date, MaxLoad, TMAX, OnPeakTotal), transform,
    Lowess = (lowess(TMAX,MaxLoad)$y))
##Verify headings and values
SummerOPM5.df [1:5,]
```

This gives the following:

```
Date        MaxLoad  TMAX OnPeakTotal Lowess
1 2008-06-02    2880 214.0       43307   2880
2 2008-06-03    2860 197.0       43166   2860
3 2008-06-04    2787 172.5       42088   2787
4 2008-06-05    2902 216.5       43333   2902
5 2008-06-06    3078 275.0       45325   3078
```

The Lowess values are the same as the MaxLoad

If I run the lowess seperately:

```
Lowess = (lowess(SummerOPM5.df$TMAX,SummerOPM5.df$MaxLoad))

Lowess$y[1:5]
```

I get this:

```
[1] 2522.221 2569.523 2603.625 2622.795 2622.795
```

Where the vector is in rank order. 
.
I am unsure if it preserves the sequence otherwise so am unsure how to fit this to the corresponding rows of my data frame.

Suggestions?

Comment: A user on LinkedIn gave me the solution:  
  
     I think I've found the source of the issue. The outcome of the   command lowess is given so that the x coordinate is ranked. Since you already have a Lowess variable in your data frame, the following line should save the values from the Lowess object into the the correct rows:


`SummerOPM5.df$Lowess[order(SummerOPM5.df$TMAX)]<-  lowess(SummerOPM5.df$TMAX,SummerOPM5.df$MaxLoad)$y`

Comment: I also think that I may be able to do it with predict type function, i.e.:

    `y.predict <- predict(y.loess, data.frame(x=Year))`

Anyone have experience with that?